# setting header inside document for some pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

How can I set different header for different sections. In this example I am looking for  replacement of `\SomeCommand`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\SomeCommand{Header 1 define here} %this sets header for all pages until another \SomeCommand found

This is multi-page text
\newpage

\SomeCommand{Header 2 define here} %this changes the header to new 

This is multi-page text
\end{document}
```

My document is NOT arranged in `\section`  and not a book. It is just plane text.

Comment: Did you try creating different page styles and using them locally?

Comment: if your document already has running heads (which `article` usually does), then they can be changed by specifying `\markboth{text}{text}` on the page on which the change is first wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no special layout requirements you can use the pagestyle `myheadings`. Then `\SomeCommand` has to set `\markright{<text>}` or maybe better `\markboth{<text>}{<text>}`. The second works also if your document is `twoside`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\newcommand*\SomeCommand[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\SomeCommand{Header 1 define here}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\SomeCommand{Header 2 define here}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think, this is available by using the `fancy` pagestyle and setting the page headers at will, by using the wrapper command `\SomeCommand`

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}

\newcommand{\SomeCommand}[1]{%
  {\noindent\LARGE \textbf{#1}\vskip 2\baselineskip}
  \fancyhead[CE,CO]{#1}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}


\SomeCommand{The Theory on Brontosaurs} %this sets header for all pages until another \SomeCommand found
\blindtext[20]
\newpage

\SomeCommand{The extended Theory on Brontosaurs} %this changes the header to new 

\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```